# How do you compare strings as arguments?

Tags: c++, string, if-statement, parameters, operator-overloading

I am trying to write a programm that reads the surname introduce and gives back the info of the student (birthdate, group, etc). The compiler does not recongize the == operator, I guess it doesnt know what to compare, either the address or the value?(I would appriciate an explanation)

I read similar cases and they suggest to use bool operator. As far as I know bool operator just returns true or false(I dont see the way to use it to print the students info)

Also I was considering usind char or using strcmp (srting functions for comparing).

```
   void find_fam ( struct st student[], int length, string & fam)
    
    {
        for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
            if ( student[i]== fam[i]){
        
        cout << "Student:\n"<< student[i].imia << student[i].otchestvo << student[i].familia << 
student[i].gruppa << student[i].grozhdenia);
                                                             
            }
    }
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and show a [mre] that anyone can cut/paste ***exactly as shown***, then compile and get your compilation error? What's shown is insufficient.

Comment: Most likely you want `if ( student[i].familia == fam)` instead of `if ( student[i]== fam[i])`

Comment: In C++ you do not need to prefix the usage of a struct with `struct`, it's implicit.

Comment: it's kinda weird you are comparing std::string with struct it is absolutely wrong.

Comment: Tip: Use `std::vector<st>` and `for (auto&& student : students)` where your argument looks like `const std::vector<st>& students`. C++ has a lot of tools here that make your life easier, like not having to pass in separate length arguments, or having to bang out `student[i]` until your fingers fall off.

Comment: `student[i]` has type `struct st`.   Assuming `string` is `std::string`, `fam[i]` has type `char` (a single character).   `struct` and `class` types do not have comparison operators defined (`operator==()`, etc) by default.   If you want to do such comparisons, YOU need to define those operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a struct like this for example

```
struct st
{
    std::string name;
    int age;
};
```

Then you would want to compare the `fam` to that member of your struct

```
if (student[i].name == fam)
```

So now `.name` is the corresponding `std::string` that you are trying to compare. Otherwise you are trying to compare a `std::string` to a `st` struct.

Comment: Could implement `operator==` but that's probably missing the point here.

Answer (score 0):

In this example you've shown, you're comparing an entire instance of the struct to the string, which is invalid.
What you should do is compare the string attribute to the string you take in.
Assuming the family of the student is called family and is of type string:

```
if(student[i].family==fam)
{
   //statements
}
```